# How To Read JSON File Offline Using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, javascript-objects

I am trying to read a JSON file using JavaScript in my local computer in `index.html` file only. My JSON file is `feed.json` as shown below.

### feed.json

```
// API callback
readFile({
    "version": "1.0",
    "encoding": "UTF-8",
    "feed": {
        "xmlns": "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom",
        "xmlns$openSearch": "http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/",
        "xmlns$blogger": "http://schemas.google.com/blogger/2008",
        "xmlns$georss": "http://www.georss.org/georss",
        "xmlns$gd": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005",
        "xmlns$thr": "http://purl.org/syndication/thread/1.0",
        "title": {
            "$t": "Title Of A Feed"
        },
        "id": {
            "$t": "ID Of The Feed"
        }
    }
});
```

I am reading the above file using the below code that I added just before `</body>` tag in my `index.html` file.

### index.html

```
<script>
function readFile(json) {
    alert(json.feed.title.$t);
}
// Calling The JSON File For This Function
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.setAttribute("src","feed.json?callback=readFile");
document.body.appendChild(s);

// Again Calling The Same JSON File
function readFileAgain(json) {
    alert(json.feed.id.$t);
}
// Calling The JSON File For This Function
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.setAttribute("src","feed.json?callback=readFileAgain");
document.body.appendChild(s);
</script>
```

I want to read this file in two functions on same page and I cant edit `feed.json` file. When I am running my above code, its reading only above function not second. So how is this possible to read this file again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to find out the solutions and I got the below one. Its working now perfectly. Through this I can unlimited functions using single callback...

### index.html

```
<script>
function readFile(json) {
    readFileAgain(json);
    readFileAgainAgain(json);
}
// Calling The JSON File For This Function
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.setAttribute("src","feed.json?callback=readFile");
document.body.appendChild(s);

// Again Calling The Same JSON File
function readFileAgain(json) {
    alert(json.feed.title.$t);
}
function readFileAgainAgain(json) {
    alert(json.feed.id.$t);
}
</script>
```

### Local Storage

Other process is using **HTML5 Local Storage**. Its also tested and working. You can use your JSON unlimited time also here freely...

```
<script style='text/javascript'>
function savePostsJSON(json) {
    if(window.localStorage){
        localStorage.setItem('JSONdata', JSON.stringify(json));
    } else {
        alert("Your Browser Doesn't Suppoet LocalStorage.");
    }
}
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.setAttribute("src","http://www.guitricks.com/feeds/posts/default/?redirect=false&orderby=published&alt=json&max-results=500&callback=savePostsJSON");
document.body.appendChild(s);
function readFile1() {
    var json = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("JSONdata"));
    alert(json.feed.id.$t);
}
function readFile2() {
    var json = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("JSONdata"));
    alert(json.feed.title.$t);
}
readFile1();
readFile2();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is `jsonp` not `json` as you can see you have a wrapper js function in the `feed.json`:

```
readFile({......})
//^^^^^^^--------^----you can see this is a function name readFile
```

As you can see `readFile` is been supposed to call after load or as a callback so in the first case it is running because the callback matches the function name.  While in the second one the callback is not matching with the function name, they are different.

For the second one:

```
readFile != readFileAgain // so it never gets executed.
```

---

So, i would suggest you to make use of `localStorage`:

```
function readFile(json) {
    if(window.localStorage && !localStorage.getItem['data']){
       localStorage.setItem('data', json); // <-----set it first here
    }
    alert(json.feed.title.$t);
}
// Calling The JSON File For This Function
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.setAttribute("src","feed.json?callback=readFile");
document.body.appendChild(s);

// Again Calling The Same JSON File
function readFileAgain() {
    var json = '';
    if(window.localStorage && localStorage.getItem['data']){
      json = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem['data']); // <------------now get it here.
    }
    alert(json.feed.id.$t);
}
// Calling The JSON File For This Function
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.setAttribute("src","feed.json?callback=readFileAgain");
document.body.appendChild(s);
```

Comment: Yes, I know that's why I am asking for the solution. So in your view, no solution there...???

Comment: there is a solution with localStorage.

Comment: @MuhammadHassan just added a code snippet. check if it works for you. atleast you can get an idea what should be done.

Comment: @Jai I think you need to stringify/parse the object to store and retrieve to/from localStorage.

Comment: Only reading `readFile` twice. Also taking long time to save my JSON file to local storage that is about 1MB...

Comment: @MuhammadHassan That is absolutely not what your question was though.

Comment: My question is same. I want to use a JSON file in two functions so that I can. What you think?

Comment: _How To Read JSON File Offline Using JavaScript?_ check the title @MuhammadHassan

Comment: and no offences but good luck if that is really working for you. I hope you got help out of SO community.

Comment: A title can define a body so that's why body is important. You can edit my title as per my question so others can get help in better way...

Answer (score 0):

The `feed.json` is in fact a JavaScript file with a single function call: it calls the `readFile()` function passing an object as argument. So it works the first time, because you have defined the `readFile` function. The other one,  `readFileAgain`, is defined but never called.

You could assign the data from your file to a global variable in the first read, then use it when needed:

```
function readFile(json) {
    window.feedjson = json;
}

var s = document.createElement("script");
s.setAttribute("src","feed.json");
document.body.appendChild(s);
```

Now the data is globally available as `feedjson`, so you can use it:

```
function getFeedTitle( data ){
    alert(data.feed.title.$t);
}

function getFeedId( data ){
    alert(data.feed.id.$t);
}

getFeedTitle( feedjson );
getFeedId( feedjson );
```

Comment: How this `function readFile(json)` will work? We never called it in your called...???

Comment: It is called from the `feed.json` file once it's loaded.

Comment: Why `Uncaught ReferenceError: feedjson is not defined` ?